# Fail safe serialization

Tags: .net, serialization, protobuf-net

Ok, we serealizing/deserializing something, but when you working with people important data,
you need to be shure that objects was serialized/deserialized correctly on 100%. For example let take the case when your application die/been forcibly closed during serialization.. in the most of cases you will get corrupted object, that is not accepteble for me, i undestant that i can manualy do baackup of file and wrote flag, lke uncommited before starting serializing and add flag commited at the end of proccess and take file from backup if it is uncommited during deserialization. That is not good because i have to make backup of very big file after every change.  Is there some build in faile safe logic in the  popular serializers in the .NET Framework or protobuf maybe? i can't find any info abaut faile safe serialization.
Or can you tell me abaut some good pattern how to make serialization faile safe?

Comment: No.  If a "very big file" is your problem then you clearly need to move to a database.  Which supports transactions.

Comment: IMO you can carve serialization out of this problem: serialize first - now you have data: how to atomically mutate data in a failsafe way? That is a well-known problem that folks like RDBMS folks know a lot about.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, transaction. unfortunately
this is a big old application and they will not switch to the database for internal reasons, there is perfomance issues. Serializer is much faster for raw data

Comment: @MarcGravell now we are doing like that...we are using uncommited/commited flags for objects. But that isn't very convinient and we have bugs from time to time.. It would be grate to have somethig like optional transactions in the serializer :). I think that is possible with some overhead.

Comment: @Brans what does "transactions in the serializer" even *mean*?

Comment: @MarcGravell maybe this can't be called by transaction. 
I mean  partial transactional serialization/deserialization of the object graph.
When we are serializing next object from graph from top to dowm we can add Identifier at the end of the object 
that mean that object was serialized correctly. Then after fail we can reliably restore part of object graph that was managed 
to serialize - we deserializing only objects from graph that have the Identifier at the end and other objects from graph we are initializing with some ERROR value. So we can restore at least part of critical data.

Comment: And we will know what objects are not serizlized... maybe they are not citicaland and we still can use objects. That why default(T) will not be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization has nothing to do with this. Your actual question is: how do I write a bunch of data atomically to disk? Here are a few options:

1. If the data is small enough to fit into a single disk cluster (512 bytes or 4K) use `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` to atomically write a single disk sector in a single write call.
2. Use transactional NTFS to atomically write any amount of data.
3. Write to a `.tmp` file and atomically rename to the wanted file name
4. Use some other means to achieve atomicity like databases (maybe even SqlLite, Esent, ...) or the CLFS of Windows.